Working with the new SQL Server PS module and -Encrypt parameter
With the introduction of the new SQL Server PS module, Microsoft has made the -Encrypt parameter mandatory for Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet.
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -query $sql -Encrypt Optional

In our environment:

We have a custom PowerShell module containing numerous Invoke-Sqlcmd
calls.
We manage thousands of servers, each with different versions
of the SQL Server PS module.

Given the variability in SQL Server PS module versions across our servers, we aim to leverage the default parameter option in PowerShell. To achieve this, we've included the following line in the $PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts profile:
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Invoke-Sqlcmd:Encrypt'] = 'Optional'

This setup works seamlessly for scripts executed from Visual Studio Code. However, functions within our custom module that call Invoke-Sqlcmd encounter failures. To address this, we've implemented an alternative approach by creating a function in the module with the following line:
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Invoke-Sqlcmd:Encrypt'] = 'Optional'

Consequently, before utilizing any function from the module, we execute the function responsible for setting the optional value.
Considering these challenges, is there a more efficient alternative? Moreover, when a PowerShell module is loaded, in which scope does it operate? How can we establish the optional value within that scope?

I guess the real answer is to get encryption working properly like you are supposed to... Also the sqlps module is now deprecated in favour of sqlserver presumably that is what you meant.

Try placing this at the top of your module, outside any function.
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Invoke-Sqlcmd:Encrypt'] = 'Optional' ;


Would this work if placed into one of the AllUsers* profile scripts?

@lit you need both. Add the line in all your user PowerShell modules (.psm1), as well as All-User-All-Hosts profile: $PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts
